# Reactjs coding with parent and child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 3 components, that is 2 child components and one parent component.
I wanted to pass the child component value to parent (only the values not the components enitirely,it should not visible in parent) and this values from parent to another child component.

Any suggestions or logic of how to proceed on this, since I don't have any guidance as of right now I had to ask here. Is the above problem possible.

The code is very complex, so I have not put here. 
Thank you

Comment: You can use `redux` to manage app state.

Answer (score 1):

When you say values, do you mean state, props, user input, something else?

**If you mean state or props**: React has a 1-way data flow, so the easiest way to accomplish this is to actually store the data at a higher level. Either store the data used by the child in the parent and pass it down to the children for consumption, or else use a store that both parent and children have access to. Either way, this will make it much easier for all components to access the data.

**If you mean user input**: one way you can accomplish this is to pass a callback from the parent component to the child as a prop, and then in the child call that callback when a user does something or changes some value. The callback function can make the data accessible to the parent on that user action, and then you can decide what to do with the data from there.

Answer (score 1):

AksharaDL,

Child to Parent — Use a callback and states

Parent to Child — Use Prop

Also here is another article explaining it:  https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Comment: You can also check out the following codepen to give you an example:  https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/dpRdKP

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution.
in parrent component you have a state. and have a `setData` method to update state. pass setData to ChildOne use props. and `data` to ChilTwo and use it

```
class StoreBanner extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data: 'whatever'
    }
  }

  setData = (data) => {
    this.setState({data})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOne setData={this.setData}/>
        <ChildTwo data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and in ChildOne you can update the parrent state

```
class ChildOne extends React.Component {
  setParentData = () => {
    this.props.setData('another')
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: ChildOne component should not display in parent,
can we pass only values?

Comment: If you want do this you can use Redux

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```js
class ParentComp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            theStateToPass: null
        }
        this.receiveDataFromChild = this.receiveDataFromChild.bind(this);
    }

    receiveDataFromChild(data) {
        this.setState({
            theStateToPass: data
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FirstChild updateMe={this.receiveDataFromChild} />
                <SecondChild stateFromFirstChild={this.state.theStateToPass} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class FirstChild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.callParentMethod = this.callParentMethod.bind(this);
    }

    callParentMethod(e) {
        let someDataToSend = "ABC";
        this.props.updateMe(someDataToSend)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.callParentMethod}>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

class SecondChild extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.stateFromFirstChild}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

however it becomes complex and  might lead to one's pulling their hair out. so i would suggest using redux , it keeps the flow simple , you have a reducer , actions and a container. everything goes with a flow and keeps it clean but it does comes with an extra overhead of more code as you will be creating container reducer and actions.